# StringBuilder insert() vs append() performance?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Is there any difference in the performance of insert() vs append() from StringBuilder class? I will be building plenty of short string as text identifiers and asked myself this question... Should I initialize SB with a separator and use insert + append or just append ?

Comment: `insert` need to copy an array to push the elements, whereas `append` just adds it to the end (so it's probably faster). But you should benchmark first.

Comment: @Tunaki so initializing SB With anything that isn't the beginning of the desired string does not make sense ?

Comment: I wouldn't do it, but it is also for clarity of the code. But before saying which is truly faster, one needs to benchmark properly.

Comment: SB is initialized with a default capacity of usually 16 chars. In your case, initializing with a more appropriate capacity may be as or more important than using insert vs append. And in that case, if your algorithm can work with appending it's likely to be more efficient.

Comment: If performance is of great concern and you are only appending elements, you might want to consider using LinkedList<String>.  Assuming you will be putting the result into a buffer or io stream it will avoid copying all the strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Knowing that:

- An `insert` at the end of the string representation is equivalent to an `append` in term of time complexity (O(n)).
- An `insert` anywhere else than at the end **can't** be obtained with an `append` (as they have differents purposes).
- For info, an `insert` may involve up to 3 `System.arraycopy` (native) calls, while an `append` 1.

You can easily conclude:

- If you want to insert at the end of the string representation, use `append`
- Otherwise, use `insert`

Doing so, you will have the best performance. But again, these two methods serving two differents purposes (with the exception of inserting at the end), there is no real question here.

Answer (score 1):

They have different functionalities and different complexities,

`insert`:

1. (ensures The Capacity of the backing array, needs to copy the old one if necessary)
2. pushes the elements leading the item at the insertion index (offset)

Where `append`:

1. (ensures The Capacity of the backing array, needs to copy the old one if necessary)
2. adds the new element to the tail of the array

So if you want to always add to the tail, then the performance will be the same since `insert` will not push any elements.

So, I would use `append`, it is just cleaner.

Answer (score -5):

According to Java API docs. You must provide offset if you use insert.

```
StringBuilder.insert(5, "String");
```

but `StringBuilder.append("string")` doesn't. I assume append has a better performance than insert.

Comment: Firstly, `insert()` method of StringBuilder is non-static method. Secondly, you need to explain why append is better than insert. Providing offset to a method doesn't guarantee worst performance than append.